# Proving complex integral on jordan region boundary equals to zero

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

> Let $D\subset\mathbb{C}$  be a region bounded by jordan curve $\gamma$. Prove that:
>
> a. $\int_\gamma z \, dz=0$
>
> b. $\int_\gamma \bar{z} \, dz\neq0$ (hint:$\bar{z}\,dz=(x-iy)(dx+i\,dy)$)

I don't know from where to start in both parts so any hint will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what kind of background you have, so here are hints for a couple of different methods:

a-1) The function $z$ has an antiderivative on $D$, so the integral vanishes by the fundamental theorem of calculus.

a-2) Since $z$ is holomorphic on $D$, the integral vanishes by the residue theorem.

a-3) More directly, write $z = \frac{z^2}{z}$ and use Cauchy's theorem (with separate cases for whether or not $D$ contains $0$; and if $\gamma$ includes $0$, take a small perturbation to reduce to the previous case).

a-4) Perform the same computation as in part (b-1).

b-1) Use Green's theorem, as the hint suggests.

b-2) Compute the integral for an arbitrary rectangle. (To simplify the computation, note that the integral is translation invariant, since $\int_\gamma 1 = 0$, and scales linearly.) Use the standard Cauchy's theorem argument to compute the integral in the general case.

Please give some indication of where you're stuck and what you've tried when posting. For example, this looks like a typical problem from the beginning of an intro complex analysis class, which would mean that you've only covered a few major results in it so far; have you tried applying any of them? There are lots of complex analysis results along the lines of, "If [condition], then $\int_\gamma f = 0$."

Comment: about part b: how can I simplify $\bar{z}$ and use it using the first method?. I know all these theorems so you are right, that's indeed a dumb question (at least the first part).

Comment: Use the hint given in your problem for part (b). And it's not a dumb question; it's just that we need more to go on than the problem statement and saying you don't know where to start if we're going to help you.

Answer (score 1):

if you multiply out and separate into real and imaginary parts then
$$
z dz = (x dx - y dy) + i(x dy + y dx)
$$
with a similar expression (as suggested) for $\bar{z}$dz. to evaluate the integrals you need to observe that $x dy + y dx$ is just $d(xy)$ whilst $xdx$ is $\frac12 d(x^2)$ and $ydy=\frac12d(y^2)$. the only term, therefore, which do not vanish when integrated round a closed curve is $xdy-ydx$, which, by Green's Theorem, evaluates to twice the area contained within $\gamma$