# Do line integrals in a convex domain vanish for a function that is only continuous?

Tags: complex-analysis, convex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration

Let $D$ be  a convex domain, $\gamma \subset D$ a rectifiable closed path and $f(z): D \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ **continuous**. Does 
$$\int_\gamma f(z)dz = 0$$
?

I think there must be a counterexample (thinking of Cauchy), but my go-to non-holomorphic continuous function the modulus $||$ does in fact satisfy this condition for circles.

Is there a nice counterexample or some other way to argue this isn't true? Or is it in fact true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a nice counterexample ...

If $\gamma$ is a Jordan curve then
$$
 \int_\gamma \overline z dz = 2iA 
$$
where $A$ is the area enclosed by the curve, see for example [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/997827/42969).

> ... or  some other way to argue this isn't true?

If $f: D \to \Bbb C$ is continous, and $\int_\gamma f(z) dz = 0$ for every closed piecewise $C^1$ curve $\gamma$ in $D$ then $f$ is *holomorphic* in $D$ – that is [Morera's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morera%27s_theorem).

Therefore, conversely, if $f$ is *not* holomorphic then there must be closed path $\gamma$ in $D$ such that $\int_\gamma f(z) dz \ne 0$.

Answer (score 2):

Take $f(z)=\bar{z}$, the complex conjugate, and take the unit circle as $\gamma$ Then

$$\int_\gamma \bar{z}\,dz=i\int_0^{2\pi}e^{-it}e^{it}\,dt=2\pi i$$

Answer (score 1):

$$f(z)=\overline z\;\;\text{is continuous but}\;\;\oint_{|z|=1}\overline z\,dz\neq 0$$

as you can easily check.

Answer (score 1):

No. Let $D= \mathbb C$, $\gamma(t)=e^{it}$ for $t \in [0,2 \pi]$ and $f(z)= \overline{z}.$

Then $\int_\gamma f(z)dz = 2 \pi i.$